# Wordpress Bootstrap image issue

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Bootstrap shortcode:

```
[box title="Random" icon="fa fa-envelope" button="More" url="#" content=""]
```

The icon is displayed okey, but I need to display an image instead of the icon. For example a .png image in the place of the icon.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using WordPress Twitter Bootstrap CSS plugin ?

Comment: This is the thing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3A9eVknqtA

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else